# how verifies the nonce produced by ethash through contract && add new opcode in EVM

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, pow, contract

I want to verify the pow of memory of one computer, then I use the `ethash` algorithm that used by `ethereum` to do the work. The problem is that the cache and dataset in the algorithm is too large for contracts. How can I verify the work?

In my opinion, the block number and account address and the nonce should pass to the contract, then contract verify it.

Or is there any other way memory base algorithm to prove one computer's memory? Thanks.

I'd like to change the structure vm.Context,

```
type Context struct {
    // CanTransfer returns whether the account contains
    // sufficient ether to transfer the value
    CanTransfer CanTransferFunc

    // Transfer transfers ether from one account to the other
    Transfer TransferFunc

    // GetHash returns the hash corresponding to n
    GetHash GetHashFunc

    // VerifyMemoryDifficulty return true if the given nonce is valid
    VerifyMemoryDifficulty VerifyMemoryDifficultyFunc

    // .......

    // Difficulty  *big.Int       // Provides information for DIFFICULTY
}

VerifyMemoryDifficultyFunc func(*big.Int)
```

But, when I call it in my solidity, it returns error:

```
Error: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
return block.difficulty(99);
^-------------------------^
```

It seems that the the solidity was checked error by compiler, my question is that what should i do, if i want to modify existing opcode with some parameters passed in?

Comment: In contract, any cache will lead to run slowly, so is there any way to avoiding to keep any large cache to verify the memory base algorithm result(nonce)